# Find the compound angle where the given angles are obtuse

Tags: trigonometry

If sinA=24/25, cosB=-3/5 where A and B are obtuse angles find (a) sin(A+B)  (b) tan(A+B)

I know I have to use the compound angle formulas
sin(A+B)=sinAcosB+cosAsinB
cos(A+B)=cosAcosB-sinAsinB
tan(A+B)=tanA+tanB/1-tanAtanB
but i'm not sure how to find the other angles from the given angles.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ an obtuse angle, $\sin x>0,\cos x<0$

$\sin x=+\sqrt{1-\cos^2x}$

And $\cos x=-\sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$